# How to use hide option for category data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this `fiddle code` http://jsfiddle.net/c4Zd8/14/ in which i am using hide option for the series data with the following code in highcahrts

```
series: {
    events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
            var selected = this.index;
            var allSeries = this.chart.series;

            $.each(allSeries, function(index, series) {
                if (selected == index) {
                    if (series.visible == true) {
                        series.hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        series.show();
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

how the same logic can be used for the categories . like jan, feb ?
Please guide.

Comment: Have you tried the [drilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown)? Maybe that could be of some use?

Comment: No. it doesn't sever the purpose. :(

Comment: It's not supported to hide specific category from a chart. You can try to workaround this by setting new data for series and setting new categories.

Answer (score 0):

see the API highcharts dochttp://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['asd', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setcategories/)

Comment: Hey , i dont want to add new categories. I just want to be able to select few categories. Like i can do with the series name

Comment: and when you select few categories what you need to doing after that

Comment: I want to redraw only with those values.

Comment: i like there are cases in which the value of categories is very less compared to other categories. So for such cases I want user to give an option to select few categories and can see the data only for those, like we can do for series

Comment: mmmm that's new case may you need post question in https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues?labels=Highcharts&state=closed

Comment: or may you need to use zoom type http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType